# ¿Cómo puedo llamar un metodo de un JFrame desde un JDialog?

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un sistema biométrico, funciona todo Ok. Pero el problema está en que en mi pantalla principal un Jframe tengo realizando la captura de una huella para el ingreso de mi cliente... todo ok... Peeero cuando llamo a mi jdialog (la función de éste es ingresar una nueva huella digital) necesito detener la captura de la huela en mi JFrame Principal para poder iniciar la nueva lectura en el Jdialog, entonces mi idea fue llamar el método público de mi `Jframe.stop();` para detener la captura, pero éste no lo hace, intenté con los eventos de `formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt);` pero tampoco lo llama.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

mira cuando creas el JDialog el trae unos paramétros, uno de ellos es la clase owner, que es el padre, cuando lo construyas creas un objeto atributo dentro del JDialog que contenga al padre para cuando lo llames OJO el JDIALOG debe ser MODAL, EJM:

En el JFRAME:

```
miDialog = new miJDialog(this,..,true); //No recuerdo que más sigue, pero también debe ser modal, es decir hay una parte donde debes darle true.
```

Ahora en el JDIALOG:

```
public class miJdialog extens JDiaglog{
    miJframe miPadre;
    public miJdialog(miJFrame miPadre, ..., boolean modal){
        super(miPadre,...,modal);
        this.miPadre = miPadre;
    }
    //etc etc
    public void miMetodoHuellaPadre(){
        this.getMiPadre.getHuella();
    }
}
```

Y listo.

Answer (score 0):

MMM oka entiendo, aún así no me reconoce el método stop de mi Jframe.
Tengo mi JDialog dentro de otro JDialog, por lo que hice lo siguiente:
Código Jframe Padre

//Llamado a JDialog 1

```
private void modificarPersonalTraining() { 
      new IngresarPersonalTraining(this, true, get.reemplazo(tb_PersonalTraining.getValueAt(tb_PersonalTraining.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString(), ".")).setVisible(true);
}
```

//Código JDdialog 1

```
javax.swing.JFrame padre;
   public IngresarPersonalTraining(javax.swing.JFrame parent, boolean modal, 
String rut) {
//CONSTRUCTOR
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
        padre = parent;
    }
```

//Llamado JDialog 2 ingresa huella 
             private void btn_IngresarHuellaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent 
           evt) {
                  new IDHuellaDigital(padre, true, id).setVisible(true);
               }

//Constructor JDialog 2
          javax.swing.JFrame padre;

```
public IDHuellaDigital(javax.swing.JFrame parent, boolean modal, int idPersonalTraining) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();
    this.padre = parent;
}

public void stopMenu(){
    padre.stop(); //Aqui me aparece un error
}
```

Comment: Esta información debe ir en tu pregunta. El apartado de respuestas solo es para responder. Edita tu pregunta y agrega esto ahí, de favor.